# SWRevealViewController panGestureRecognizer with pageViewController iOS(side menu on swipe)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller, uipangesturerecognizer, swrevealviewcontroller

1. How can I use panGestureRecognizer to open sideMenu if I already have some other swipe gestures in the frontViewController(in my case it is  HomescreenViewController)?
   My frontViewController contains a pageViewController with  5 pages.So left swipe and right swipe are already enabled for the pageViewController.

   I used the following code in the viewDidLoad of frontViewController:

   ```
   _sideButton.target = self.revealViewController;
   _sideButton.action = @selector(revealToggle:);
   [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
   [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.tapGestureRecognizer];
   ```

   This will not do the work along with the pageViewController right swipe.
   Then I use this code:

   ```
       self.revealViewController.draggableBorderWidth = self.view.frame.size.width / 2;
   ```

   But this is also not working.I am using the latest SWRevealViewController version 2.4.0

   This is the view hierarchy of my frontViewController.
   HomescreenViewController>pagerView>PageviewController>listingViewController
2. Also,When the side menu appears ,the portion of the frontviewController is active and when I try to close the side menu by swiping towards left, it recognises it as the pageviewcontroller swipe. I hope the solution to the first problem will solve this as well.

***UPDATE(answer):***
Look accepted answer for question number 2.
For first question,if you are experiencing a problem like mine,just create a view with width 20 pixels towards the left side using the code below and add panGestureRecognizer to this view(in `viewWillAppear`).

```
 SWSwipeViewForPanGesture=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,20, self.view.frame.size.height)];
_SWSwipeViewForPanGesture.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubview:_SWSwipeViewForPanGesture];
[_SWSwipeViewForPanGesture addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
```

Also,I had to add the following code in `- (void)revealController:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController didMoveToPosition:(FrontViewPosition)position` method This is a delegate method.So,you should confirm to the delegate in the viewdidload.

```
    [_SWSwipeViewForPanGesture addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:_SWSwipeViewForPanGesture];
```

Thats it.It simply works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution For First question:**

You cannot recognize two swipe gesture on one view. So basically, answer for your first question is not possible. You cannot  swipe for  `SWRevealViewController` in your `pageview` controller.

**Solution For Second question:**

Write this code in  `HomescreenViewController` `ViewDidLoad` method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
SWRevealViewController *  revealController=[[SWRevealViewController alloc]init];
    revealController = [self revealViewController];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:revealController.panGestureRecognizer];
       revealController.delegate=self;
    [revealController panGestureRecognizer];

    [revealController tapGestureRecognizer];
    [btnSideMenu addTarget:revealController action:@selector(revealToggle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}
```

After that add this delegate method of `SWRevealViewController` in to your `HomescreenViewController`.

```
- (void)revealController:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController didMoveToPosition:(FrontViewPosition)position
{
    if (revealController.frontViewPosition == FrontViewPositionRight)
    {
        UIView *lockingView = [UIView new];
        lockingView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:revealController action:@selector(revealToggle:)];
        [lockingView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
        [lockingView addGestureRecognizer:revealController.panGestureRecognizer];
        [lockingView setTag:1000];
        [revealController.frontViewController.view addSubview:lockingView];


        lockingView.backgroundColor=[UIColor ClearColor];

        NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(lockingView);

        [revealController.frontViewController.view addConstraints:
         [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[lockingView]|"
                                                 options:0
                                                 metrics:nil
                                                   views:viewsDictionary]];
        [revealController.frontViewController.view addConstraints:
         [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[lockingView]|"
                                                 options:0
                                                 metrics:nil
                                                   views:viewsDictionary]];
        [lockingView sizeToFit];
    }
    else
        [[revealController.frontViewController.view viewWithTag:1000] removeFromSuperview];
}
```

May be, it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Bhumica.The second problem is solved.Is there a way to disable rightswipe on pageviewcontroller when the index is zero?Or can we add a transparent view (like you just did) towards the left end of the HomescreenViewController and adding  revealController.panGestureRecognizer to it?

Comment: In Ipad splitviewcontroller,I saw an app in which when we are at the index 0,the swipe gesture works to bring the menu towards the front.

Comment: @abhi1992 but if you will put transparent view on pageview's index 0 than how would you swipe to go to the next page .?

Comment: I meant to add a view with thickness say 20 pixels towards the left side of the view.

Comment: @abhi1992 Do one thing take a transparent view on pageview's o index if swipe left on that transparent view than open menu and if it will swipe right than open pageview's 1 index.

Comment: see the EDIT,my idea will work...anyways thanks for the second answer.It was a great help.

Comment: This works perfectly. However, I have two controllers to reveal, one on the left and one on the right. I can't do your trick (20px view on left and 20px view on the right) because we can't add the Gesture Recognizer to two different views.

Any idea on how I could achieve to reveal my left and right menus by swiping (and not swiping in the PageViewController)?